# React - The `component` prop provided to ButtonBase is invalid. Please make sure the children prop is rendered in this custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, material-ui

I am trying to use custom SVG icons to replace the base icons from Pagination component of Material UI (V4), and I keep getting this error in the console:

> Material-UI: The `component` prop provided to ButtonBase is invalid.
> Please make sure the children prop is rendered in this custom component.

Now the code I'm using in that scenario is the following (relevant pieces):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pagination, PaginationItem, PaginationRenderItemParams } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronLeft } from 'assets/ChevronLeft.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronsLeft } from 'assets/ChevronsLeft.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronRight } from 'assets/ChevronRight.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronsRight } from 'assets/ChevronsRight.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronDown } from 'assets/ChevronDown.svg';

const ResourceTable = (props: TableProps): JSX.Element => {

  const showPaginationItem = (item: PaginationRenderItemParams) => {
    if (item.type === 'first') {
      return (
        <PaginationItem
          {...item}
          component={React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement>(function Link(props, _) {
            return <ChevronsLeft {...props} />;
          })}
          shape="rounded"
        />
      );
    } else if (item.type === 'previous') {
      return (
        <PaginationItem
          {...item}
          component={React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement>(function Link(props, _) {
            return <ChevronLeft {...props} />;
          })}
          shape="rounded"
        />
      );
    } else if (item.type === 'next') {
      return (
        <PaginationItem
          {...item}
          component={React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement>(function Link(props, _) {
            return <ChevronRight {...props} />;
          })}
          shape="rounded"
        />
      );
    } else if (item.type === 'last') {
      return (
        <PaginationItem
          {...item}
          component={React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement>(function Link(props, _) {
            return <ChevronsRight {...props} />;
          })}
          shape="rounded"
        />
      );
    } else return <PaginationItem {...item} shape="rounded" />;
  };

  return (
    <Pagination
            count={totalPages}
            onChange={handleChangePage}
            page={page}
            renderItem={showPaginationItem}
            showFirstButton
            showLastButton
        />
  );
};
```

The Material UI docs suggest that I should "avoid inline functions and pass a static component to the component prop instead. I tried that as well, and the error is still there. Is there something I am missing, that would allow me to get rid of the error?

Thank you very much for your help;

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same issue, turns out solution is straightforward -- rather than passing a custom function to the `renderItem` prop, do this:

```js
<Pagination
  count={totalPages}
  onChange={handleChangePage}
  page={page}
  renderItem={(item) => (
    <PaginationItem components={{ previous: ChevronLeft, next: ChevronRight} {...item} /> 
  )}
  showFirstButton
  showLastButton
/>
```